# AngularJS Checkbox and $validators

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of checkboxes that are backed by a model that is an array of ids.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkers" value="black" ng-model="board" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkers" value="white" ng-model="board" />
```

the model would look like:

```
 [ 'black', 'white' ]
```

so there is a number of 'hacks' to get this to work like one would think and even a directive [checklist-model](http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/).

My problem is I have a directive that does dynamic validation using ngModelController's `$validators`.  That directive looks something like this:

```
module.directive('validator', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            var rules = $parse($attrs.validator)($scope);
            ngModelCtrl.$validators.myValidator = function(val){

                // this is simplified, real case is much more complex
                if(rules.minSelections > 0){
                    return !(val.length <= rules.minSelections);
                }

                if(rules.required){
                    return !val.length;
                }

            }
        }
    }
});
```

I attached it to my checkboxes like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkers" val="black" validators="{ minSelections: 1 }" ng-model="board" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkers" val="white" validators="{ minSelections: 1 }" ng-model="board" />
```

problem is the `val` in the `myValidator` validation always returns true/false.  I can't ever seem to get ahold of the 'actual' model I need despite several different approaches and even using that directive.  On a note: the $validators runs BEFORE the click on that directive.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Checkboxes are true/false by default. I don't think 'val' is a valid attribute. Perhaps you need to use ng-true-value="black' ng-false-value="". I'm assuming you do not actually want a RADIO button here (Ie you can choose EITHER black or what but not both). Current setup allows you to choose BOTH black and white.

Comment: the val was a typo ... no radio buttons ... i tried the true/false deal and had no luck since it was attributes and wouldn't let me call fns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating my own checkbox directive and manually triggering validation to happen.

If you take a look below, you can see how I watch the collection and if the value has changed I commit the value and re-trigger the validation manually.

Heres the code for others:

```
define(['angular'], function (angular) {

    // Use to style checkboxes, bind checkboxes to arrays, and run validators on checkboxes
    // Modified from: https://github.com/bkuhl/angular-form-ui/tree/master/src/directives/checkBox
    var module = angular.module('components.checkbox', []);

    /**
     * <check-box ng-model="isChecked()"></check-box>
     * Required attribute: ng-model="[expression]"
     * Optional attribute: value="[expression]"
     */
    module.directive('checkBox', function () {
        return {
            replace: true,
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                'externalValue': '=ngModel',
                'value': '&'
            },
            require: 'ngModel',
            template: function (el, attrs) {
                var html = '<div class="ngCheckBox' + ((angular.isDefined(attrs.class)) ? ' class="'+attrs.class+'"' : '') + '">'+
                    '<span ng-class="{checked: isChecked}">' +
                        '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="isChecked"' + ((angular.isDefined(attrs.id)) ? ' id="'+attrs.id+'"' : '') + '' + ((angular.isDefined(attrs.name)) ? ' name="'+attrs.name+'"' : '') + '' + ((angular.isDefined(attrs.required)) ? ' name="'+attrs.required+'"' : '') + '/>'+
                    '</span>'+
                '</div>';
                return html;
            },
            controller: function ($scope) {
                if (angular.isArray($scope.externalValue)) {
                    $scope.isChecked = $scope.externalValue.indexOf($scope.value()) >= 0;
                } else {
                    $scope.isChecked = !!$scope.externalValue;
                }

                $scope.$watch('isChecked', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    if (angular.isDefined(newValue) && angular.isDefined(oldValue)) {
                        //add or remove items if this is an array
                        if (angular.isArray($scope.externalValue)) {
                            var index = $scope.externalValue.indexOf($scope.value());
                            if(newValue) {
                                if( index < 0 ) $scope.externalValue.push($scope.value());
                            } else {
                                if( index >= 0 ) $scope.externalValue.splice(index, 1);
                            }
                        } else {
                            //simple boolean value
                            $scope.externalValue = newValue;
                        }
                    }
                });
            },
            link: function ($scope, $elm, $attrs, ngModel) {
                $scope.$watchCollection('externalValue', function(newVal) {
                    if (newVal.length) {
                        ngModel.$setTouched();
                        ngModel.$commitViewValue();
                        ngModel.$validate();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });

    return module;
});
```